# MySQL-Update table takes so long

Tags: mysql

I have a talbe with ~110k rows and 20 columns and no indexes. I wrote a query to update 9 columns of this table JOIN with another table which has many indexes. And the query took forever to run. I really dont know why. Here is my query:

```
UPDATE tonghop a JOIN testdone b 
ON a.stt = b.stt 
SET a.source = b.source, a.pid=b.pid, a.tenbenhnhan = b.fullname, 
a.orderdoctor=b.orderdoctor, a.specialty = b.specialty, a.rdate = b.rdate, 
a.icd_code = b.icd_code, a.servicegroup = b.servicegroup;
```

Really appreciate if someone could help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Query you are executing is without a WHERE Clause which means that it is going to be executed on all the 110K records, and your Join Column "stt" must be indexed on both the tables in order to achieve better performance.

You should add an index on the column "stt".

Answer (score 1):

Without indexes on both of the columns, JOINS are going to be slow.
You are most likely forcing MySql to read every single one of the 110k records to check whether they match.
With an index, MySql knows where these records are, and can quickly find them.

Try adding an index on tonghop.stt.

You could also try and run an EXPLAIN on the query, to see if it indeed does a so-called "full table scan".

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/using-explain.html

Comment: Just a note: EXPLAIN on UPDATE is MySQL 5.6 / MariaDB 10 thing only, but UPDATE can be rewritten to SELECT which is generally almost equivalent in terms of plan